# Use Google Drive as an external editor

Tags: editor, google-drive-api, edit, docx

I have a website that stores, parses and display .docx files. I want to give users a way to edit those files.

I don't want to embed a third-party widget in my website and I thought that I could use Google Drive API. My idea is that I can give user a button “Edit in Google Drive” which back to my server somehow.

The problem is that I haven't found neither API function that allows to do that nor examples of such approach.

Am I on the right way? Can my idea work? If yes, then how can I do it?

Comment: I'm not sure about the editing step (haven't looked at it), but for the bits Zig describes, depending on your preferred language, you may be interested in my post http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2014/03/docx4j-and-google-drive/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the drive api. There is one to upload a new file and optionally convert it to native google format.
To upload it, read about using oauth2 to authorize storing it on the user's drive. User must have Drive of course.
After the user finishes editing, they press a button or something on your site so you use the drive api to either read the gdoc and convert yourself to docx or use the drive api to download as docx.
Both uses of drive api are explained in the docs.